# Displaying icon on html page

Tags: html, font-awesome

Displaying icon within a div tag column class.

This is the code I am using:

```
<div class="col-md-3 text-center">

 <div class="icon">

 <i class="fa fa-tablet"></i>

</div>
```

once save and display on the page nothing shows up. Kindly can someone help I am working on a live project but am stuck right now.

Comment: When HTML isn't working, it is a good idea to check it with a validator such as the [W3C Markup Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/).

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine for me. 
Probably there's a problem with your CDNs or location of files you are using

Try this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="col-md-3 text-center">
  <div class="icon">
    <i class="fa fa-tablet"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "it works" is never an answer. At best it's a comment.